# postfix warning: pipe_command_write: write time limit exceeded

Tags: centos, email, postfix, exchange-2010, email-server

I am trying to recieve a very large email which is being forwaded from exchange server. File size of 80GB. I have increased the file size limit in main.cf

However after an hour I got the following error in the log. How can I resolve this?

```
Aug 22 14:27:35 titan postfix/pipe[12144]: warning: pipe_command_write: write time limit exceeded
Aug 22 14:27:35 titan postfix/pipe[12144]: 0855B57D9: to=<enkive@enkive.vp.local>, relay=filter, delay=5835, delays=6/0.07/0/5829, dsn=5.3.0, status=bounced (Command time limit exceeded: "/data/enkive/enkive-1.1-CE/support/filters/postfix/enkive-socket-filter/dist/enkive-socket-filter")
Aug 22 14:27:35 titan postfix/qmgr[12123]: 0855B57D9: removed
```

My configuration:

main.cf

```
message_size_limit = 819200000
mailbox_size_limit = 819200000
command_time_limit = 10000000000s
ipc_timeout = 10000000000s
sendercheck_time_limit = 10000000000s
```

master.cf

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -      smtpd
        -o content_filter=filter:dummy

filter    unix  -       n       n       -       -      pipe
          flags=Rq user=nobody null_sender=
          argv=/data/enkive/enkive-1.1-CE/support/filters/postfix/enkive-socket-filter/dist/enkive-socket-filter localhost 2527 ${sender} ${recipient}
```

I have managed to send 10MB file. I am using postfix to forward emails from exchange to enkive which is a mail archiving tool

Answer (score 2):

Email was never designed to deal with gigabyte-sized messages; consider using something - anything! - more appropriate for large file delivery.

> Aug 22 14:27:35 titan postfix/pipe[12144]: warning: pipe_command_write: write time limit exceeded

You already received the huge file; this is postfix failing to send it to the pipe(8) transport you configured as its destination.

That said, postconf -d does not show your configuration, so the information displayed is useless.

You should include the relevant lines from master.cf and any main.cf parameters related to this transport.

Comment: updated answer withe new data

Comment: As adaptr said - postfix accepts the file, but when it tries to pass it on to enkive, enkive takes too long to handle it so postfix stops. Mail really **really** isn't a good way to handle an 80Gb file.

Comment: sorry i meant 80MB